# SSH remote port forwarding through bastion server

Tags: ssh, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to establish a remote port forwarding to my Mac (target 4004) via a bastion host and Server-A to a Port (1555) on Server B.

So the whole connection is:

> Mac:4004 => Bastion:22 => A:22 => B:1555

And the target is my Mac should have a Port 4004 forwarded from B:1555.

**What is working so far?**

1. I can connect to Server A with the command `ssh user-bastion@user-A@server-A@server-bastion`
2. On Server A I can establish a connection e.g. telnet to B:1555
3. On my windows client I can remote forward the port B:1555 to my local machine via Putty.

I'm now looking for the ssh command to establish this connection on my Mac.

**Commands I tried:**

Of course I have already searched for it and I've already tried different versions.
e.g.

- ssh -fNT -R 1555:localhost:4004 -J user-bastion@user-A@server-A@server-bastion server-B
- ssh -N user-bastion@user-A@server-A@server-bastion -R server-B:1555:localhost:4004

I always receive message like "Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 1555"

Comment: My mistake was that I mixed up remote and local port forwarding. The solution is `ssh -N -L 4004:server-B:1555 user-bastion@user-A@server-A@server-bastion`

Comment: Props for solving your own issue in 2 hours.